# How to assign user input to a string and compare to another string

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get user input from a user and then act on it with either gathering more user input, or executing a script immediately, however I'm running into a bit of an issue. Here's the code I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    read -p "Would you like to run the script with custom dates? (y/n) " answer

    case $answer in
    [yY]* ) export ANSWER=Y
            break;;

    [nN]* ) export ANSWER="N"
            exit;;

    * )     echo "Not a valid response, please answer with Y or N";;
    esac
done

if [$ANSWER = Y]
then
    echo "Answered yes"
else
    echo "Answered no"
fi
```

When I enter Y for my answer, I get an error: `./getRatings.sh: line 18: [Y: command not found`

I'm extremely new to bash and am sure I'm missing something super simple, does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `./getRatings.sh: line 18: [Y: command not found` means that,
in the script `./getRatings.sh`, on line 18, the shell try to execute the `[Y` command, but it could not find it.
This is because you entered `Y` as the answer,
and then `[$ANSWER` was interpreted as `[Y`.
But you want to use the `[` builtin,
and for that you need to put a space after the `[`.
And btw also before the `]`.

Not putting a space after `[` is akin to not putting a space after any command. For example instead of `ls some/path` if you write `lssome/path` that obviously won't work.

So the fix is as simple as:

```
if [ $ANSWER = Y ]
```

Btw, since you exit when the answer is not yes, the `echo "Answered no"` will never be reached.

Also, you most probably don't need to `export` the `ANSWER` variable.

As you're new to shell scripting, I recommend to check out http://www.shellcheck.net/. You can copy-paste Bash scripts there and it can spot and explain bugs and bad practices for you.

Comment: I knew it was something simple... Thank you for the help, I'll accept your answer in 11 minutes!

Comment: Just saw your edit, thanks for the tip with the exit, I grabbed that cookie cutter code off another site to use - I rarely work with scripting languages so a lot of my code is copied from other sources and then built upon. Also thanks for that link!